# how to add '.html' to a custom route in magento 2?

Tags: php, xml, magento2

Please tell me how to add .html sufix to custom route URL ? Here is my current URL: https://example.com/filter/search and here is what i need: https://example.com/filter/search.html

**/filter/** - is my route defined in my extension.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i wonder why you "need" it

Comment: i need it for SEO

Comment: no you really dont. (trust me i use to work in SEO optimisation )?

Comment: please explain....tell me more about this situation as an answer here.

Comment: search engines dong care about file extensions.

Comment: @smith in my case, the system was using `.html`for categories and product. But not for custom route URLs such as **privacy** and **contact us** or **wishlist** etc. Q1: is it ok to mix extensions? So if I wanted to unify all to have `.html` then I would need to add `.html` to custom route (what this question is asking). Else, I would go to Admin > Config and remove `.html`.